# Delphi: define const double from binary representation

Tags: delphi, type-conversion, ieee-754, rad-studio

**Background**

I want to create a unit test to test some rtl aspects of Delphi, and in order to do this I want to use very specific IEEE floating point values that I want to create directly from their binary representation.

I have come up so far with this routine, and it actually does the job.

```
function TestIEEEDouble.BuildDoubleFromRawInt64(const aBinData:UInt64):double;
begin
  CheckEquals(sizeof(aBinData),sizeof(Result),'sizeof(aBinData),Sizeof(Result)'); // ensures we dont mess up with wrong types
  Move(aBinData,Result,sizeof(Result));
end;
```

It is used as follows (bindata may still be wrong, but thats not the question):

```
procedure TestIEEEDouble.Setup;
begin
  inherited;
  FSmallestPositiveDouble:=BuildDoubleFromRawInt64($0000000000000001);
  FSmallestNegativeDouble:=BuildDoubleFromRawInt64($8000000000000001);
  FLargestPositiveDouble :=BuildDoubleFromRawInt64($7FEFFFFFFFFFFFFF);
  FLargestNegativeDouble :=BuildDoubleFromRawInt64($8FEFFFFFFFFFFFFF);
end;
```

**Question**

Is there syntax that would allow creating a `const double` directly from a binary (hex) representation looking something like this:

```
const
  cSmallestPositiveDouble:double=double($0000000000000001);
```

Where the result obviously should NOT be `1.0` (it is with this syntax) but (close to) `4.94065645841247e-324`

Comment: You can use runtime-only functions in inline constant declarations: `begin const cSmallestPositiveDouble: Double = BuildDoubleFromRawInt64($0000000000000001);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer with my own initial solution, the syntax is a bit more extensive than I like, but this seems to do the trick using a variant record and implicit type casting.

Nice feature/side effect is that you can quickly see binary representation and double representation together in the inspector/watchwindow.

```
type
  RDoubleHelperRec=record
    class operator Implicit(aRec:RDoubleHelperRec):double;
    case Bin:boolean of
      True:
        (BinData:UINT64);
      False:
        (DoubleData:double);
  end;
...
class operator RDoubleHelperRec.Implicit(aRec: RDoubleHelperRec): double;
begin
  Result:=aRec.DoubleData;
end;
```

then when using it, declare as const:

```
procedure TestIEEEDouble.TestCompareValueBoundary;
const
  cSmallestPositiveDouble:RDoubleHelperRec=(BinData:$0000000000000001);
begin
  CheckEquals(0,CompareValue(FSmallestPositiveDouble,cSmallestPositiveDouble),'CompareValue(FSmallestPositiveDouble,cSmallestPositiveDouble)');
end;
```

Comment: You could remove the (useless) extra `Bin` field and just use `case Boolean of`

Comment: @OndrejKelle: I did, changed it to integer and added `ByteData:array[0..sizeof(Double)-1]` so little/big endian gets to be visible too. I ave created testcases now for `Single`, `Double` and `Extended`

Comment: See related issue https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-32213

Answer (score 5):

This can be done directly thru unions:

```
type  // In a union all variables share the same address
  TAll= packed record
    case Integer of
    1:( d: Double );
    2:( i: Int64 );
    3:( f: TFileTime );
  end;

const  // Define the constant just like you would define an array
  ALL: TAll= ( i: 43 );
```

The rest is obvious: either you now access `ALL.d` to see how `43` as `Int64` is interpreted as `Double`. Or do it the other way around. Likewise you can even check how the `TFileTime` interpretation looks by accessing `ALL.f`.

When dealing with or checking binary keep in mind that the byte order is also important ([LE versus BE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)) - especially when reading from different storage types (FS versus RAM).

Comment: Cool, I came up with something similar, But added the implicit operator to reduce source code lines.

Comment: See related issue https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-32213